# Independence: norm v.s. direction of a standard multivariate normal vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Suppose that $v\sim N(0,\sigma^2 I_n)$ and with $||\cdot||$ denoting the Euclidean norm, define
$$
u=v/||v||\quad\text{and}\quad w=||v||.
$$
I've been told that $u$ and $w$ are independent and I see an argument [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61733/dependence-between-direction-and-magnitude-of-multivariate-normal-random-vector) on MO but I can't really follow it because I don't see the justification behind the step that states the joint distribution function of $u$ and $w$ (in the link, $f_{u,y}(u,y)$). Can someone please explain that step or, better, provide a more elementary proof of the independence of $u$ and $w$?

**Argument for $n=1$ case**.
We have, for $w_0\geq 0$,
\begin{align*}
\Pr[(w\leq w_0) \cap (u=+1)]&=\Pr[0<v\leq w_0]=\Pr[w\leq w_0]\underbrace{\Pr[u=+1]}_{1/2},\\
\Pr[(w\leq w_0) \cap (u=-1)]&=\Pr[-w_0\leq v< 0]=\Pr[w\leq w_0]\underbrace{\Pr[u=-1]}_{1/2}
\end{align*}
from which independence follows.

Answer (score 5):

Multivariate standard normal density function is in the form $f(x)=\exp(-\|x\|^2)$ where $x$ is the vector. Observe that $f(x)$ doesn't care about $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ and only cares $\|x\|$, hence conditioned on any slice $\|x\|=a$, $f(x)$ is a constant which means all directions are equally-likely (i.e. uniform distribution).

Now, the conditional distribution of direction is independent of $\|x\|$ and is always uniform e.g.
\begin{equation}
P(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\big|\|x\|=a)=constant.
\end{equation}
Since all marginals are uniform, the overall distribution $P(\frac{x}{\|x\|})$ is uniform as well hence
\begin{equation}
P(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\big|\|x\|)=P(\frac{x}{\|x\|})
\end{equation}
But this is the very definition of independence as it implies (via Bayes rule)
\begin{equation}
P(\frac{x}{\|x\|},\|x\|)=P(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\big|\|x\|)P(\|x\|)=P(\frac{x}{\|x\|})P(\|x\|)
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks. Silly question. What is the constant in $\begin{equation}
P(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\big|\|x\|=a)=constant.
\end{equation}$?